# How to distinguish Firebase IdToken for same user?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

We are developing an app (Let's assume "**MyAPP**") using Flutter and exploring Firebase for Authentication, I have gone through Firebase documentation, and found that firebase Auth returns **IdToken** to identify user, and the app (client) can also pass this to the backend (server side).

We have a plan to develop SDK to be integrated in the merchant app as well, So I need to distinguish between **IdToken** generated by our app (**MyAPP**) and **IdToken** generated for same user in our merchant app (where our app SDK is integrated).

Sample:

Let's say user U1 with Mobile M1 login to MyAPP , IdToken generated I1

**U1 ----> M1 ------> I1 (IdToken in MyAPP)**

Now when this user mobile (U1) tries to login via merchant app,

**U1 -----> M1  ------>I2 (IdToken in merchant app using our SDK)**

I want to put some logic in our backend API's like if the user is coming from  merchant app than he can't do certain operation.

Answer (score 0):

`Firebase.auth.currentUser.uid` is a string.

Then you could check if which uid is from which app.

Comment: UID will be same in both cases, only IdToken will be different, and i need to distinguish at backend API, whether user is coming from MyAPP or merchant app (where MyAPP SDK is being used)

Comment: @Peter Haddad Can you pls help on this ?